# Rearranging two lists simultaneously

Tags: vb.net

I have two lists. I sorted list 1 from lower to higher value. So indexes change in first list as compared to their original position. E.g. before sorting, list 1 is (4,3,8,6,0) and after sorting, list 1 becomes (0,3,4,6,8). In this case index 0 is moved to index 2 after change and so. So now I want to perform same change of indexes in my second list regardless of its data i.e. index 0 should be moved to index 2 in list 2. Any thought on how can that be done?

Comment: Your design is wrong. Instead of parallel collections, treat both values as one, either using `Tuple` or custom class. Read http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections.aspx

Comment: I would agree with MarcinJuraszek for the vast majority of cases.  In the very small minority of cases where parallel lists is appropriate, there is an overload of `Array.Sort` that sorts two parallel arrays.  You can call `ToArray` on your lists, sort them both and then call `ToList` on each array.  That will give you two new lists rather than sorting the originals though.